# Formatting time intervals with localization in Java

Tags: java, time

We have intervals (elapsed time between two oracle timestamps) stored in our database as seconds and we format them at front end with Java.

What we would to achieve on the reports is a format of the form "HH:MM" or "HH:MM:SS", with the time  separator ":" localized as it happens with dates and time information, i.e '.' for Italian and ':' for English.

Unfortunately the **date-related formatting classes**, like SimpleDateFormat, do not work** because we can expect durations above the 24 hours. 
We **don't want to employ 3rdy party library** as well.

Do you know how we can solve this problem?

TIA

Comment: FYI, the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defines a sensible format for [Durations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations), `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`. The required `P` begins each instance, and the `T` separates the date portion from time portion. Solves the ambiguity problem of confusing the colon-format for a time-of-day rather than a duration. Solves the 24-hour problem as this format is not limited by the 24-hour convention. And you can normalize the value if you want. For example, you may choose between `PT48H` or `P2D`.

Comment: By the way, if you were willing to consider using an external library, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library supports the ISO 8601 standard as it's defaults in parsing and generating string representations of date-time values. This includes the Durations format I described in comment above.

Answer (score 2):

If you want hours of more than 24 you can print this separately.

```
int hour = time / 3600000;
String duration = time + new SimpleDateFormat(":mm:ss").format(new Date(time));
```

To support other locales you could do this more complicated example.

```
int hour = time / 3600000;
String duration = hour
                + DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, locale)
                            .format(new Date(time % 3600000).substring(1);
```

What this will do is use the locale specific format for the last digit of the hour + mins + secs and prepend the additional digits of the hours.  Note: this will not work for negative times.

Comment: Of course this is trivial. But this is not localized! How do you do something like DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, locale) for any locale?

Comment: @nagylzs Can you give an example of a Locale where HH:MM:SS is printed differently?

Comment: Italian? http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/forms/v3r5m1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.form.designer.locales.doc%2Fi_xfdl_r_formats_it_IT.html

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the OP's question, and it was not about localizing a time interval to a GIVEN locale, but to convert a long time interval for the CURRENT locale.

Comment: Yes, some more things I have noticed: DateFormat.MEDIUM will sometimes use "h" instead of "H" for the hour part which is wrong because 17 becomes 5 PM. And yes, you also need to add support for negative intervals. So a full featured solution cannot be implemented with 2 lines of code. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a date object, say "2000-01-01", then add your seconds to it. Then you can use this to extract the localized version of the time:

```
DateFormat format = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, locale);
String formatted_time_part = format.format(some_date_object);
```

Finally you still need to add elapsed days! I'm affraid that localization of long intervals (days, months, years, centuries) has no corresponding API in Java but I might be wrong. So you will have to figure out that for yourself.